# How to test the rendering of the right template

Tags: scala, testing, playframework-2.0, specs2

I want to test that my application is rendering the right template in play framework 2.3.x, something like:

```
"Index" should{
    "render index template" in new WithApplication{
      ...
      val result = call(controller.index, FakeRequest())
      someFunction(result) must render(views.html.index)
    }
}
```

Something similar to what rspec does:

```
response.should render_template("success")
```

Is it possible, what's the recommended way in play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple controller function like that, I would check the content of the response, versus the content of the rendered template. Note that a template is rendered as `Html`, so you must call `toString` to compare with the content of the `Result`. I like to check the content type and status of the `Result` as well.

```
"Index" should {
    "render index template" in new WithApplication {
        val request = FakeRequest(GET, '/') // I prefer using the router, but it doesn't matter that much.
        val Some(result) = route(request)
        val expectedContent = views.html.index().toString

        contentAsString(result) must equalTo(expectedContent)
        contentType(result) must equalTo("text/html")
        status(result) must equalTo(OK)
    }
}
```